# Using `dynamic` keyword in Unity 2017 with VS 2017

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, dynamic-language-runtime

Unity 2017 introduced an experimental .NET 4.6 Mono backend. Given that Mono seems to support the [dynamic language runtime](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/), I'm wondering whether we can finally use `dynamic` in Unity games (even if it's just PC).

Trying this out with a simple example:

```
dynamic foo = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
foo.bar = "bar";
```

results in an error saying `CS0656  Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'`. This is after switching to the .NET 4.6 profile.

From what I can gather this is normally solved by adding the Microsoft.CSharp.dll as a reference but for a Unity project, there doesn't seem to be an option to add such a reference.

Does anyone know how to get this to work in Unity 2017 with VS 2017?